# Finding the probability that the temperature is between x and y

Tags: probability, statistics

Hello I have a problem that I can't seem to come to the proper conclusion with. It is as follows:

What is the probability that a randomly selected day in August will have a temperature greater than 85 but less than 100. Mean is 80 with a std dev of 8 assuming temperature is distributed normally.

I missed this on a test and I'd like to know where I went wrong so if someone could work it out step by step I would appreciate it very much. Thanks

Comment: Are we assuming temperatures are normally distributed?

Comment: Yes my bad. Assume that the temperatures are normally distributed.

Answer (score 2):

If your $\mu$ is 80, and $\sigma$ is 8, you're looking for $$P(85\le X \le 100)$$ Which can be found like this: $P(X\le 100)-P(X\le 85)$, letting $X=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ when you sub in your given info you can use the standard normal table and get your $z$ statistic (as I have been told they're called). So now you're looking to get $P(z \le 2.5)-P(z \le .625)$, and I'm assuming you can do the rest.

Comment: Yeah, I do the following:

Find P(Z < 2.5) = 0.99379
Find P(Z < 0.625) = 0.734014

So then I subtract and get
0.2598

This is exactly what I put on the test. However, it was marked wrong.

Comment: Then it's time to ask your instructor about the problem.

Comment: @Chris you should let us know so we know whether we had the right answer or not ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you believe the distribution is normal (which it is *not*) you are asking for the probability that you are between 0.625 standard deviations and 2.5 standard deviations above the mean.  You should have a table of the cumulative [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) that will give you the answer.  (For the Wikipedia table you will have to interpolate between 0.62 and 0.63)